# Need guidelines to improved image processing library

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, class-library

I am working on image processing library in c#. 
want to improve performance/speed and better memory management.
I am using Bitmap class and its just array manipulations.
Can someone suggest me, how to improve it. any guidelines?

Comment: Have you profiled your library?  What are your specific performance concerns?

Comment: No, is there any tool you can suggest?, It takes too much time to run and take more memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to find out where your problem lies.  I would suggest using the built-in Visual Studio profiler to figure out where your execution performance bottlenecks are.

There's an MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) that explains how to use the profiler.